# Custom master page is showing inside the dashboard designer (PPS)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, performancepoint

I have some issues with Dashboard Designer. When I am creating a new report, my custom master page is showing inside the designer.

How i can remove this?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: I have the same issues. How do you solve it? Thanks